# 2011 Lexus RX: hydraulic hood lift need to hold 5 seconds to stay in place

Tags: lexus, hood, lexus-rx

When I open up the hood, I need to raise up the hood and hold it for 5 seconds to make the hydraulic lift work to hold the hood in place.

I do not hear any "gas" sound from the hydraulic lift.

Is this expected behavior? Or I need to replace the hydraulic lift?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

This is not expected behavior for a hydraulic strut that supports a hood or trunk lid. It will not improve on its own, and may collapse without warning. Do not rely upon it.

The strut should be replaced.

Comment: OK, I will use the part here: LEFT) https://parts.lexus.com/p/Lexus_2011_RX-350/SUPPORT-ASSEMBLY---HOOD---LEFT/63272301/534500W170.html RIGHT) https://parts.lexus.com/p/Lexus_2011_RX-350/SUPPORT-ASSEMBLY---HOOD---RIGHT/63271801/534400W200.html